# RestKit: create an object without saving it

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have an edit "my entity" controller, where I'd like user to make changes in cells and then save it only if user taps the 'save' button. The problem is, that cells are reusable, so i can't be sure that my data is stored in them. That's why I want to save it somewhere, and duplicating all properties from my object to controller doesn't seem to be a good pattern.

Can I create my object using the class I've already implemented with `RestKit` without saving it to Core Data? I can't find such method. The only one is:

```
[[MyObject alloc] initWithEntity:<#(NSEntityDescription *)#> insertIntoManagedObjectContext:<#(NSManagedObjectContext *)#>];
```

What obviously does save into Core Data :/. What is the best way to do it properly?

Comment: Hi, did you ever manage to correctly solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: @el-flor yes, i'm not using restkit but other frameworks. In fact I migrated away from Core Data as well. FFMDB is much faster when working with huge databases. Anyway, if you mean such behaviour in Core Data I'm rather convenced it's not possible.

Comment: God, thanks for the motivation ;-) That sucks. I'll try and find a way. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the object in a another NSManagedObjectContext. For example:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
tmpContext.parentContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
```

Now create the new object in the `tmpContext`. If you want to rollback the changes you simply call

```
[tmpContext rollback];
```

Or save it:

```
[tmpContext save:&error];
```

Comment: Bit hacky however indeed, it will work. Thanks for the idea :)